# Union control states

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I would like to make binary or on `UIControlState`. In obj-C I would use binary `|` operator, but in swift I have to use:

```
imageView.setBackgroundImage(blueBackground, forState: UIControlState.Highlighted.union(.Selected))
```

But code above (especially if I have more than two states to make union) hard to understand. Is there any simpler way to do that like:

```
imageView.setBackgroundImage(blueBackground, forState: UIControlState.Highlighted | UIControlState.Selected)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `OptionSetType`, just put them into an array, like this:

```
 imageView.setBackgroundImage(blueBackground, forState: [.Highlighted, .Selected])
```

Comment: Thanks. What was what I was looking for.